# Adding new host to apache ignite data grid

Tags: java, ignite

I have just started using Ignite grid and have a basic question after running an example class provided by Apache Ignite. The name of the class is CacheApiExample and the code excerpt is

```
Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")
IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("CACHE_NAME")
```

I am able to start multiple nodes (Ignite terminology)/multiple jvms on the same host.

My question is that when I scale horizontally and add a new machine on which when i run the above code, it should automatically become a part of the CACHE_NAME cache which was created by the code above, what settings do I need to change so that the new machine also becomes a part of the distributed cache ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With configuration provided in "examples/config/example-ignite.xml" and with default configuration nodes should find each other on one host and join to the cluster. In case when you want run nodes on different hosts, you will need to configure [DiscoverySpi](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config) and [CommunicationSpi](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/network-config)

By default cache has Partitioned cache mode, so that means that all server nodes will have a portion of partitions on them. You could read about PARTITIONED caches [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#section-partitioned-mode).

Comment: Rightly mentioned, example-ignite.xml imports a default xml also, I just configured the ip and port number in that machine and when i started a node on a new host, it got detected. Thanks!